# How to read text file in real time and then capture a webcam video frame using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, video, logging, frame, capture

I am using portmon to real time log a software start command to a movable x-y stage. I need matlab to read this log file as fast as possible and then trigger the capture of 10 frames from a webcam a second after the start command is read.

How would I go about this process. I have the image acquisition toolbox but I am a total newbie to matlab programming.

Comment: I suggest you'll do this in Python instead, for two reasons: 1) Python code usually runs much faster than Matlab code, which is important if you want to run in real time. 2) Python is free.

Comment: Hi, We have only matlab and we need to log the change in a second and capture a frame after a second. Anyone else think this could work?